# Why does the following javascript function always return true?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return

I have the following function, it will always return True. Any ideas why and how to avoid it? Thanks folks.

```
function validateStatuses(xyx){
var umm = ugh[xyx];
var selects = $('#cont_'+ugh.xyz+' .status_select');
var codes = $('#cont_'+ugh.xyz+' .status_code');
for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    var value = selects[i].options[selects[i].selectedIndex].value;
    if (value == 'new'){
        for (var j = 0; j < codes.length; j++) {
            var blagh = codes[j].options[codes[j].selectedIndex].value;
            if(blagh == 13){
                $('#info_dialog').html('');
                $('#info_dialog').append("<p>You are trying to process a bill ("+bill.name+") with a STATUS of NEW and a STATUS CODE of NONE. Please correct this issue before you proceed!</p><hr />");
                $('#info_dialog').dialog({
                    buttons:{
                        Cancel: function(){
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                    });
                billCounterAdd();
                return false;
            }//end if           
        }//end for
    }else{
        return true;  //this is the problem;
    }//end if
}//end for
}//end Function
```

Comment: It returns `true` because, at some point, `if (value == 'new')` will have the condition evaluated to `false`, hence driving code flow to the `else` branch.

Comment: Any time you have to comment the closing `"}"` of a block it usually means the block is too long.

Comment: Off-topic, but as you seem to be using jQuery, you might look at its [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) functions, which might help simplify the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dare say you have at least one select whose value isn't `'new'`. Because you've done a `return true;` in the `else` clause, the first select with a value that isn't `'new'` will cause the function to return true.

It looks like it does have a false return route (if there's a `'new'` select at the beginning and there's a code select with the value `13`), but perhaps that test case didn't come up in your testing.

In terms of figuring out what's wrong with things like this, there's nothing quite like walking through the code and watching it run line-by-line in a decent debugger. All major browsers have them built in now (finally), so you can see exactly what's happening and inspect variables, etc.

Comment: Right on fine sir and a mighty fine thank you to everyone for the prompt response. I felt rather red faced after reading your description. I moved the return true statement outside of the last For loop to get the desired effect.